InvalidOperationException when fetching joined data with Entity Framework in Blazor Server
I'm working on a Blazor server-side project where I need to fetch and join data from multiple tables using Entity Framework Core in the OnInitializedAsync method. However, I'm encountering the following error:

InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

Here is my code below:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    PeopleTypes = await DbContext.PeopleTypes.Select(pts => new PeopleType
        {
            Id = pts.Id,
            TypeName = pts.TypeName
        }).ToListAsync() ?? new List<PeopleType>();

    Peoples = await DbContext.People.Select(pl => new People
        {
            Id = pl.Id,
            Name = pl.Name,
            CompanyId = pl.CompanyId,
            TypeId = pl.TypeId
        }).ToListAsync() ?? new List<People>();

    CompanyLists = await DbContext.CompanyList.Select(cl => new CompanyList
        {
            Id = cl.Id,
            CompanyName = cl.CompanyName
        }).ToListAsync() ?? new List<CompanyList>();

    ClassDetails = await DbContext.ClassSessionsDetails
    .Where(csd => csd.CsID == CSId)
    .Where(csd => csd.CompanyId == selectedCompany)
    .Select(csd => new ClassSessionDetails
        {
            Id = csd.Id,
            CsID = csd.CsID
        }).ToListAsync();

    classMembersData = await DbContext.ClassSessionsDetails
        .Join(DbContext.ClassSessionsMembers,
            csd => csd.Id,
            csm => csm.CSD_Id,
            (csd, csm) => new { csd, csm })
        .Join(DbContext.People,
            combined => combined.csm.PeopleId,
            people => people.Id,
            (combined, people) => new { combined.csd, combined.csm, people })
        .GroupJoin(DbContext.CompanyList,
            combined => combined.people.CompanyId,
            company => company.Id,
            (combined, companies) => new { combined.csd, combined.csm, combined.people, company = companies.FirstOrDefault() })
        .GroupJoin(DbContext.PeopleTypes,
            combined => combined.people.TypeId,
            peopleType => peopleType.Id,
            (combined, peopleTypes) => new { combined.csd, combined.csm, combined.people, combined.company, peopleType = peopleTypes.FirstOrDefault() })
        .Select(result => new ClassMembers
            {
                PeopleId = result.people.Id,
                Name = result.people.Name,
                CompanyId = result.company.Id,
                CompanyName = result.company.CompanyName,
                PeopleTypeId = result.peopleType.Id,
                PeopleTypeName = result.peopleType.TypeName
            }).ToListAsync();

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

Does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this issue, or how I can improve my query to avoid concurrent operation conflicts? Thank you.

Hi @eza, please modify your code like this, and let me know if it works for you.

hi Jason,  I've modified my code as you suggested and it works perfectly now. thank you!

Hi eza, do you mind me summarize it as answer below, thanks

of course not, please go ahead

Merge multiple queries into one query to avoid multiple asynchronous calls to DbContext. This can avoid concurrent operations and improve performance.
Here is the sample
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var result = await (
        from csd in DbContext.ClassSessionsDetails
        join csm in DbContext.ClassSessionsMembers on csd.Id equals csm.CSD_Id
        join p in DbContext.People on csm.PeopleId equals p.Id
        join cl in DbContext.CompanyList on p.CompanyId equals cl.Id into companyGroup
        from company in companyGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join pt in DbContext.PeopleTypes on p.TypeId equals pt.Id into peopleTypeGroup
        from peopleType in peopleTypeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where csd.CsID == CSId && csd.CompanyId == selectedCompany
        select new ClassMembers
        {
            PeopleId = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            CompanyId = company != null ? company.Id : (int?)null,
            CompanyName = company != null ? company.CompanyName : null,
            PeopleTypeId = peopleType != null ? peopleType.Id : (int?)null,
            PeopleTypeName = peopleType != null ? peopleType.TypeName : null
        }
    ).ToListAsync();

    classMembersData = result;

    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

